# A lot of blank space when page resize

Tags: html, css

Im making a one page HTML that needs to be displayed on different screen sizes. I made the code to adapt 100% of the size of the browser, but the problem is, one of the div which takes 80% of the height, would leave blank space when on smaller screens.

i want to know, how can the content inside of the div (.second) fit inside the space so that it'll display nicely?

the website is http://emailblasting.epizy.com/index2.html

i can paste the code here but it'll be too long.

thanks guys

Comment: For small screens use another styles with `media query`

Comment: where is the extra space?

Comment: Nidhin, when you resize the page, or in chrome, you display the page as a device that has small screens such as 600x800. the div two would leave a lot of space between it and three

Comment: The css for two has fixed height : 80%. That is causing the issue.

Comment: `I can paste the code here but it'll be too long.` Please make a "minimum similar" example

Comment: Don't do much engineering, just use bootstrap.

Comment: its not that i dont want to use bootstrap, but client want to put this inside an email, and bootstrap is not supported (gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "table" do it with simple div.
give this class to your banner image

```
.image{
  width:*in pix*
  height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
 }
```

For better UI try to use bootstrap
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Comment: its not that i dont want to use bootstrap, but the client wants to make a HTML email, so bootstrap is not supported.

Comment: ok then replace your table tag with div ..hope it will work..your iamge is hiding behind the banner because of this